# How to create an AudioQueueInputCallback in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-audio

In the Apples **Swift 3** API *Core Audio* the method `AudioQueueNewInput(...)` is used to create a new recording audio queue object.

One of the arguments *inCallbackProc* is of Type `AudioQueueInputCallback`. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1501687-audioqueuenewinput?language=objc) for the full declaration of the `AudioQueueNewInput` function.

The declaration of `AudioQueueInputCallback` itself looks like this:

```
typealias AudioQueueInputCallback = (UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, AudioQueueRef, AudioQueueBufferRef, UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, UInt32, UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) -> Void
```

I want to create a function, which I can safely pass into the `AudioQueueNewInput` function. What I tried looks like this:

```
func audioQueueInputCallback(inUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
                           inQueue: AudioQueueRef,
                           inBuffer: AudioQueueBuffer,
                           inStartTime: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                           inNumPackets: UInt32,
                           inPacketDesc: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) {
   // Handle stuff
}
```

Sadly Xcode can't seem to convert my function to the type `AudioQueueInputCallback`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of your callback function should be an AudioQueueBufferRef , not an AudioQueueBuffer.

See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/audioqueuebufferref

Comment: Wow, what an easy fix. Thank you!